# Get order subtotal value in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I use the module for calculating delivery by local carrier, but the module don't calculate shipping costs to the total.
In the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php` I added the following code to take the amount of shipping and subtotal:

```
     <?php $a = array(
         get_post_meta($order_id, 'Order_subtotal', true),
         get_post_meta($order_id, 'Econt_Customer_Shipping_Cost', true));
     ?>
     <tr class="total-cost">
         <th><?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
         <td><?php echo array_sum($a); ?> <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?></td>
     </tr>
```

As a result, I get only the value of `"Econt_Customer_Shipping_Cost"`, but not from `"Order_subtotal"` to get the total.

What can be used to get a working subtotal?

Comment: My code doesn't work?

Comment: I tried again - it works! My mistake is that I copied all the code and got error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','` I delete `, // or $order->get_total( )` and evreting works great! :)

Comment: I update my code, If I missed something please tell me fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `'Order_subtotal'` does not exist in wp_postmeta table for `'shop_order'` post-type.

**Last very important thing:** Don't overrinde templates directly in woocommerce plugin, to avoid loosing your changes when plugin is updated. You can **better** override this files by **copying** this **`'templates'`** folder to your active child theme or theme and rename it woocommerce. 
See this reference: [Overriding WooCommerce Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)…

---

**Changing your code *(the answer)***

As you have already at the beginning of this template `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`, you can use the class [WC_Abstract_Order](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html) native functions `get_subtotal( )` or `get_total( )` directly from `$order`, without using `get_post_meta()` Wordpress function.

I have changed some things in your code:

```
<?php 
    $display_sum = $order->get_subtotal( ); // or $order->get_total( );
    $display_sum += get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Econt_Customer_Shipping_Cost', true );
    $display_sum .= ' '. get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( );
?>
<tr class="total-cost">
    <th><?php _e( "Total:", "woocommerce" ); ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $display_sum; ?></td>
</tr>
```

This should work as you want it, but this will not update the order total, it just display it.

References:

- [Class - WC_Abstract_Order](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html)
- [WooCommerce get order total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755713/woocommerce-get-order-total/33828850#33828850)

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, Many thanks for the code !!! With a single change it works perfectly for me in email-order-detayls file! I changed only this: `$display_sum += get_post_meta( $order_id` to `$display_sum += get_post_meta( $order->id`

Answer (score 2):

Try this code `$order_total = get_post_meta ($order_id , '_order_total', true);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$order->get_subtotal_to_display();`

Comment: This works without any issue, thank you